# Runing the sample code for google assistant sdk giving SyntaxErorr: invalid syntax

Tags: raspberry-pi, sdk, google-assistant-sdk, google-assistant, google-assist-api

I'm trying to run the following code for starting my google assistant with the raspbery pi:

```
googlesamples-assistant-pushtotalk --project-id my-dev-project --device-model-id my-model
```

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/env/bin/googlesamples-assistant-pushtotalk", line 5, in <module>
    from googlesamples.assistant.grpc.pushtotalk import main
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/googlesamples/assistant/grpc/pushtotalk.py", line 29, in <module>
    from tenacity import retry, stop_after_attempt, retry_if_exception
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tenacity/__init__.py", line 292
    from tenacity.async import AsyncRetrying
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
pip install -U tenacity
```

Solve for me...